# MySql date = CURDATE() not working with 2 LIKE Condition

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a SQL query with to filter the data based on Current date and two LIKE criteria the problem I'm having with this code is that it shows me the data for all dates

if I run the code with only one like condition it works correctly

```
SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE date = CURDATE() and Teamname LIKE '%SOUQ%'
```

But below is not working correctly (giving the results for all dates)

```
SELECT * FROM `attendance` WHERE date = CURDATE() and TeamName LIKE '%NOON%' OR Teamname LIKE '%SOUQ%'
```

Please guide me with what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need  ()  around AND ( ... Or ...)   the AND operator  has priority over the or operator

```
  SELECT * FROM `attendance` 
    WHERE date = CURDATE() 
    and ( TeamName LIKE '%NOON%' OR Teamname LIKE '%SOUQ%')
```

if you don't use () your code is equal too

```
  WHERE(  date = CURDATE() 
    and  TeamName LIKE '%NOON%' ) 
  OR Teamname LIKE '%SOUQ%')
```